# How do I kill with poison?

Tags: papers-please

There is some point in the story where you receive poison to kill someone, but every time I click on the poison I die. I tried shaking the dusts over the papers or using the seal with them, but no luck.

How do I apply the poison on their passports without dying??

Comment: This question makes me what to play this game again once I get home. Classic.

Comment: Out of interest, which day do you receive the poison envelope?

Comment: @unbindall Day 20

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a video that shows you how to do it:

Basically, you have to open the poison card 3 times (don't touch the poison).

You open the card by clicking on the arrows 3 times.

Here's also an image:

[image]

Comment: I missed the last step opening the envelop. I thought it was to close it again

Comment: Linked video is dead.